# What is the reason behind using node embeddings?

Tags: geometric-deep-learning, graph-neural-networks, graphs, embeddings

I was reading Chapter 3 from the following book ([here](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Ewlh/grl_book/files/GRL_Book.pdf)) on graph representation learning. The chapter is about node embeddings.

**Question:** What is the point of using node embeddings?

Do we use them:

- to save space/memory by mapping our graph into a form which is of lower dimension?
- to find a representation of the graph which can be fed into a neural network?
- perhaps some other reason?

It isn't clear to me what the actual purpose/end-goal is of finding a representation is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have also been reading about graph neural networks, which aim to find an embedding for the nodes (but I don't understand why that is of any use to us).